# How to get parent view of checkbox in listview items

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-animation, android-listfragment

my listview item has a text-view, image-view, and check-box. when i click on check-box i get event to setonclick listener, i need to remove the deleted row with animation.

So, for this if i use the checkbox view, i get animation appearance only for check-box and not for other views like textview, imageview.

Here is the animation code

```
 OnClickListener CheckboxListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 

             final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.splashfadeout);
                v.startAnimation(animation);
                Handler handle = new Handler();
                handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       mcompletecallback.completePressedItem(cursorHelper.primaryKey);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        animation.cancel();
                    }
                }, 1000);
}
}
```

In this `v` is the checkbox view, but i want to know the view which holds checkbox, if i apply animation on it, it work smooth. But i want to know how to get it here?

Here is my anim xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

My adapter code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String todayDate = Utilities.getTodayDate();
    String tomorrowDate = Utilities.getTomorrowDate();


    ViewHelper viewholder = null;
    DividerHelper dividerviewholder = null;


    int view = getItemViewType(position);

    if(view == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        //perform header actions
    }
    else
    {
        //Cursor c = (Cursor) getItem(position-cursorPosition);

        Cursor c = (Cursor) getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            viewholder = new ViewHelper();

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);

            viewholder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_title);
            viewholder.Notes = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_notes);
            viewholder.Status = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_item_is_completed_checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            viewholder.Status.setTag(viewholder);
            viewholder.Status.setOnClickListener(completedCheckboxListener);

        }
        else
        {
            viewholder = (ViewHelper)convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewholder.primaryKey = c.getInt(0);
        viewholder.Notes = c.getString(9);
        viewholder.Title = c.getString(3);




    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: That option is not there, i guess i tried. if we click on checkbox, is there a way can we get the clicked view i.e full row?

Comment: Every view should have getParent() to get the parent of the view. Else you can write the onClickListener() into the getView of the listadapter and you can set the animation to the entire rowView(in getView()) of the list.

Comment: Try to set parent reference as setTag() to CheckBox And try to access this reference at onClick with getTag()...

Comment: I need animation to be performed only upon click of the checkbox, not on the whole view.

Comment: Hi harish, i tried that method, but if i do that i'm getting correct animation but its leaving few of the views blank. whole listview behavior is getting changed :(. I think thats not best way to try also

Comment: @Naruto You can set the animation to the entire row in the onClickListener of the checkbox. So that the view will be animated when you click on the checkbox

Comment: @Sripathi, thanks for reply, i need to go inside the view i.e i need to show the preview screen, but if i click on checkbox the item needs to be deleted. but while deleting i need to show a small animation kind like moving from left to right, or it gets disappear slowly like that

Comment: @Naruto I also came to said that. You can set the onclick listener of the checkbox in the getview of the specific row itself. So you just try and let me know. You can achieve what you expect.

Comment: @Sripathi, i have already posted the `OnClickListener CheckboxListener` above, in getview method i'm setting this listener to all the checkbox items of listview. i have posted the code above. Here i'm seeing only checkbox is getting animated i.e i get animation effect only on checkbox, but not on other items like textview, imageview. For testing i tried by putting entire view object in tag and in checkbox clicklistner i accessed the tagged object and applied animation, it work smooth. But here the behaviour of listview is wired & its not good idea to do also. So i'm struggling to achieve

Comment: Ok can you post your adapter? atleast getView()? I can show you my idea with your code..

Comment: ok, Sripathi, right now i'm using my phone for reply, i will post the code as soon as i reach home, please respond, surely i will update the getview code for you. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi sripati, i tried via getparent, now animation is coming but its leaving me a blank item just after the animation, dont no where is the mistake. i hope we are closer, can you please help. i have posted getview code.

Comment: shall we continue our discussion via chat, if you dont mind please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54454/discussion-between-naruto-and-sripathi).

Comment: Hi sripathi, i'm guessing the issue could be that, we need to find out a way to remove the animation from convertview object once its animated and removed from list. But i'm not finding concrete way, any help please

Answer (score 1):

Apply the onItemClickListener on that listview and when you click on that row you will get

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //here "view" is your complete row that you clicked where you can find your checkbox

}
```

Comment: Hi Navajot, thanks for reply, i want animation to perform only on clicking on checkbox, not on clicking on listview

Comment: Hi Naruto, then you can set the tag of complete row view to the checkbox view "checkbox.settag(row)", and whenever you click on checkbox you will get that row from the tag "(View)checkbox.gettag()" of that clicked checkbox.

Comment: For testing i tried by putting entire view object in tag and in checkbox clicklistner i accessed the tagged object and applied animation, it work smooth. But here the behaviour of listview is wired & I'm getting balk views after deletion of items. and its not good idea to do also.

Comment: That you need to handle on your getView of your listview adapter, not to populate views that are deleted by maintaining an arraylist or something.

Comment: You can view the source code of this library https://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList , this will solve your problem

Comment: you have posted `onItemClick`, we get this event trigger when we click on any item of listview. onclick i want some other operation, but if we tap on checkbox i want animation. Now i'm deleting the item upon click of checkbox, but i'm asking how to animate it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Sripathi & Navjot Bedi`

i am able to figureout how to do,

We need to call `View v1 = (View) cb.getParent();` to get the parentview of checkbox, and then

call animation on V1 object,

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v1.getContext(), R.anim.splashfadeout);
            CompleteUponCompletionofAnimation(animation, cursorHelper.key);
            v1.startAnimation(animation);

```
public void CompleteUponCompletionofAnimation(Animation fadeout, final int pk)
    {
        fadeout.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //your change at end of animation
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

also in convertview, remove the animation by putting NULL

```
if(convertView == null)
{
}
else
{
if(convertView.getAnimation() != null)
convertView.setAnimation(null);
}
```